# Включение overflow в зависимости от высоты страницы

Tags: html, css, прокрутка, overflow

У меня есть div содержащий внутри 3 блока. тоже div.
логотип, текст и div с кнопками.

```
.autoDiv {
            overflow: auto;
            height: complex;
        }

<div class="autoDiv">
</div>
```

уменьшении страницы у меня начинают div наползать друг на дурга. как настроить автоматическое включение scroll?

Comment: через min-width max-width

Comment: это ширина. это у меня уже сделано) а уменя проблема именно по высоте

Comment: блин, точно, на скорости перепутал слова) лучше приложите более явный участок кода с комментарием где и при каком условии должно скроллить, попробуем помочь

Comment: да я бы приложил но это оочень большой кусок. и как его сжать я не знаю. там адаптивная верска более 80 режимом на разные сочетания только по шиине. css 3500 строк) короче мрак. но мне нужно простая довольно вещь (возможно это сложно но мне кажется прсотым просто я не делал так) - это сделать так чтобы scroll появлялся только при стягивании div по ВЫСОТЕ. например div 360px как только стало 359 тут же включается scroll.

Comment: если я правильно понял проблему... попробуйте для тех блоков, где нужен скролл использовать такие свойства: `display:block;
max-height:100px;
overflow:scroll;`

Answer (score 1):

сделал отдельный маленький стиль вот такой для div обрамляющего

```
.autoDiv {
    overflow: auto;
    height: fit-content;
}
```

и это сработало.

Comment: мой вариант не пробовали? интересно, сработал бы

Comment: да он тоже сработал попробовал.=)

Comment: С fit-content будут проблемы с кроссбраузерностью.

Comment: `да он тоже сработал попробовал.=)` понял, отлично, спасибо)

Comment: тоже хотел написать про кроссбразурность,но уже упомянули.
IE EDGE FIREFOX не поддерживают height:fit-content